# sendmessage() doesn't work inside a function

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, listbox

If I do it like this, it works - it populates the listbox:

```
BOOL CALLBACK MnDlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (Message)
{
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT id FROM tremreg ORDER BY id DESC");
    while (res->next())
    {
    int i = res->getInt("ID");
    std::string str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
    char *cstr = new char[10];
    strcpy_s(cstr, 10, str.c_str());
            SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_lbList), 
                              LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)cstr);
    }
    delete res;
}
break;
```

However, if I wanted to be tidy and put it inside a function, like this, it would no longer populate the list, even though the function itself DOES run.:

```
VOID fRefreshListID()
{
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT id FROM tremreg ORDER BY id DESC");
while (res->next())
{
    int i = res->getInt("ID");
    std::string str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
    char *cstr = new char[10];
    strcpy_s(cstr, 10, str.c_str());
    SendMessage(GetDlgItem(g_hMnDialog, IDC_lbList), LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)cstr);
}
delete res;
}



BOOL CALLBACK MnDlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (Message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
{
    fRefreshListID();
}
    break;
```

For some reason, SendMessage() refuses to work while inside a function. `g_hMnDialog` is a global handle for the main dialog which contains ALL of the controls, listbox included.

**PROBLEM**: SendMessage(), works and populates the listbox outside a function. However, the function does not populate the listbox once called, even though it contains the same code.

**QUESTION**: Why does my SendMessage() does not work inside a function, and what steps should I take to make it work?

**BONUS QUESTION**: Where would be the best place to call this function (once/if) it works to constantly refresh the listbox?

Comment: Side note - `char *cstr = new char[10]` is leaking memory and is unnecessary anyway. For your question, there's no reason other than the possibility of using a different window handle, debug and make sure you're sending to the same `HWND` in each version or pass it as a parameter to your function.

Comment: I see. That's what I suspected, and I did try to pass the handle to no effect. Not even using the global handle of the main dialog works. What would you suggest instead of `char *cstr = new char[10]`? In the end, it was the only way I finally made the SendMessage() to actually work and compile.

Comment: `str.c_str()` is already all you need (it's a `const char*`), copying it to another `char*` is redundant, just cast it to an `LPARAM`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked without the copying now. But still, I played around with various handle passing measures, but something goes wrong all the time. And using global handle makes neither work it seems, nor does the same `hwnd` seems to be sent from `DlgProc` to `fRefreshListID(HWND hwnd)`. I am at a loss, literally every other function gets `hwnd` just fine, but not this one. Guess it's copy/paste in case I need to refresh the listbox, which I will.

Comment: Your `fRefreshListID` does **not** contain the same code as your `WM_INITDIALOG` handler. The former uses `g_hMnDialog` in its call to `GetDlgItem`, while the latter uses the `hwnd` parameter passed to your dialog procedure. This is worth investigating.

Comment: @IInspectable Both, at least I would assume, are handles for main dialog. Wouldn't DlgProc get it when the dialog is created? `g_hMnDialog` is assigned to the dialog creation. I did try to pass the `hwnd` to the function and `GetDlgItem` instead of using the global handle. It didn't work either. I tried passing the global handle as an argument to the function. And when nothing worked, I posted this issue here. **And according to the debugger, the handle's value inside the function changes at each line.**

Comment: Two handles identifying the same window have the same numeric value. You cannot have aliases for `HWND`s. The way you describe it in your last comment sounds like they have different values, which implies that they reference different windows. Also, if the value appears to change at each line in the debugger you're most likely debugging a release configuration, or have stale/outdated .pdb's pulled by the debugger.

Comment: @IInspectable The code that assigns `g_hMnDialog` will go like this: `g_hMnDialog := CreateDialog(..., MnDlgProc);`  So `g_hMnDialog` won't be assigned until `CreateDialog` returns, but `WM_INITDIALOG` also happens before `CreateDialog` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious explanation would be that `g_hMnDialog` is not yet initialised at the time when you call `fRefreshListID()`. Personally, I would avoid using global variables where possible. When you call `fRefreshListID()`, you have the window handle to hand to it makes sense to pass it as a parameter to `fRefreshListID()`. The function would look like this:

```
void fRefreshListID(HWND hwndDialog)
{
    ....
}
```

You should be checking for errors when you call API functions. My expectation is that `GetDlgItem` returns `NULL` because `g_hMnDialog` is not valid. You then blindly pass that `NULL` on to `SendMessage`. I recommend that you add some error checking.

Your string handling is all off too. You are making it much more complex than needed. You can write it like this:

```
HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hwndDialog, IDC_lbList);
if (hwndList == NULL)
    // deal with this error
std::string str = ...;
SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str.c_str());
```

If you want the function to repopulate the list you will need to clear the list, or at least replace items. As it stands, each time you call your function you will add more items to the existing ones.

What is the best time to call the function while the application is running? That cannot be answered in detail with the information you provided. It depends on what your application is doing. What do you want to trigger a refresh? Do you want it to be based on a timer and so be a polling approach? Or do you want to listen for an event that tells you that the list contents are out of date. Only you can really answer those questions.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if I missed something so obvious, but using your advice I rewrote the function. It works now. Now I feel dumb. Nonetheless, thank you.